# Hosting multiple websites on IIS with SSL

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, iis, domain

Using IIS on a dedicated Windows Server 2016 I have a site running on my server (dev.timesavr.net) with SSL.  This site has been running for at least a year now. 
 Now I've added a second site on the same server with a different domain (dev.benjicare.com) but I'm not able to access it from outside the server.

Both sites are bound to dedicated IP addresses.  I've seen lots of suggestions on this site (and others) to use "Host Headers" in order to make IIS host multiple domains, but those can only work with unsecured sites.  I need to use IP addresses because I need to use SSL for both, so both websites in IIS are bound to their own unqiue IP addresses.

dev.timesavr.net is already accessible via SSL. I haven't yet got a certificate for dev.benjicare.com but at this point I'm trying to just get it working without SSL.  I can access it in a browser only if I'm on the server itself (via RDP), but from any other machine I can't access it.  After it tries to connect for about 30 seconds it eventually times out and says "This site can't be reached".

I've already created an A dns record to point my IP to dev.benjicare.com and that's working as it should as you can see here:  https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/dev.benjicare.com

I've also checked the firewall to see if the WWW inbound rule on port 80 was restricting IP addresses but it's not. What else am I missing here to make this work?  It seems like this should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Host headers have worked with TLS for years (via SNI).  IIS will allow multiple SSL sites to use the one IP under one of two circumstances.  1) SNI is enabled. 2) The same certificate is bound to both sites and has the hostnames listed in the subjectAltName field.

Comment: Some background https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Comment: Greg W, what is this subjectAltName field you speak of?  Is that a field in IIS somewhere?  Also, how is SNI enabled in IIS 10?  The link that Lex Li posted shows the SNI tab in a module called HTTP API, but that module does not exist in IIS 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `dev.benjicare.com` is currently pointing to `10.20.21.114` whis is not you public IP.

[image]

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses

From `dns` `pointing` rectify the correct `public IP` first! and also check the `binding settings` in `IIS` to check whether you have correct binding settings for your puclic ip to you website. 
see https://www.sherweb.com/blog/cloud-server/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/

If you want to use same public ip 174.142.191.69 for dev.benjicare.com , first point it from domain service provider. not the private address 10.20.21.114 you are currently using. Or else you will go out of nowhere with it. Then change the binding to "all unassigned"

[image]

Comment: This is very interesting.  How did you get your ping to show you the reply from address with that IP?  When I ping in command prompt or powershell it only returns "Request timed out" four times, except on the server where it returns 10.12.124.12 as the reply address.  And how would I fix that anyway?  My bindings in IIS are correctly pointing to 10.12.124.12.  What else is there?

Comment: dev.benjicare.com--->pointing ot private address which is 10.12.124.12. that is not routable to outside world. only from you vpn itself. you need a public ip such as 174.142.191.69 used for dev.timesavr.net . simple. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/private-IP-address

Comment: ip address shows because from your domain service provider you have mapped dev.benjicare.com with 10.20.21.114 which is not a routable, pingable via internet. its pingable and approachable only via local network in this case its just only withni your vps. untill you correctly point a new or existing public ip, you wont get it working to access outside the vpn. simple as that. also  see in my screenshot  my ping reply says "Destination not reachable because my local network does not have 10". ip range

Comment: Thanks to you both.  I was under the impression that this was a public IP but I've confirmed with my host that this was indeed the wrong IP address.   Problem solved.